# how to give a user a role?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, user-roles

How possible give a user the 'adminstrator' role? for example I made a user with wp_insert_user(array(..., 'role' => 'Administrator') but it doesn't effect on role of user. 
thanks.

Comment: Have you tried "Administrator" in all lower case? Please don't truncate your code to the bare minimum like that. If I wanted to throw that code into a dev stack and test it I couldn't. You don't need to post irrelevant code but try to post complete blocks of reasonably relevant code.

Comment: Oh thanks I found the problem i should have wrote it  'administrator' because in usermeta table it must be a:2:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;s:13:"bbp_keymaster";b:1;}

Answer (score 1):

[image]

or

```
/ NOTE: Of course change 3 to the appropriate user ID
$u = new WP_User( 3 );

// Remove role
$u->remove_role( 'subscriber' );

// Add role
$u->add_role( 'editor' );
```

Super Admin – somebody with access to the site network administration features and all other features. See the Create a Network article.

Administrator – somebody who has access to all the administration features within a single site.

Editor – somebody who can publish and manage posts including the posts of other users.

Author – somebody who can publish and manage their own posts.

Contributor – somebody who can write and manage their own posts but cannot publish them.

Subscriber – somebody who can only manage their profile.